# Getting Error while using PDO: Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null

Tags: php, pdo

I am learning PDO, and I am keep getting this error, I did some searches and nothing resolves the issue. Here is the code I am Using:

index.php:::

```
require_once 'database/Connection.php';
require 'Task.php';
$pdo = Connection::make();

$statement = $pdo->prepare("select * from todos");
$statement->execute();
$tasks= $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Task');

<ul>
        <?php foreach ($tasks as $task) : ?>
            <li><?= $task->description; ?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
```

Connection.php:::

```
class Connection {

    public static function make() {
        try {
                $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=mytodo', 'root', 'mysql');
            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                die($e->getMessage().' DB Could not find');
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: Try change `27.0.0.1` to `localhost`

Comment: what is the error u r getting?

Comment: @S.I. changed to localhost, same error

Comment: @VikasUmrao getting this error::-->   Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in E:\Ampps\www\jeffry\index.php on line 27

Comment: @VikasUmrao If I use pdo connection statement in index.php without requiring Connection.php it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use return keyword as:

```
class Connection {

    public static function make() {
        try {
                return $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=mytodo', 'root', 'mysql');
            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                die($e->getMessage().' DB Could not find');
            }
    }
```

}